# Download de XML pelo navegador, sem abrir o arquivo

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, xml, download

Preciso que o sistema baixe um arquivo XML, libere o arquivo em si, sem abrir ele no navegador, tem como?

Comment: Acredito que sim.

Comment: Sim tem como é utilizar `readfile` (php), `XMLHttpRequest` (javascript) e `ajax` (jquery)

Answer (score 2):

Tem sim. Faz assim

```
<?php 
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="file.xml"');
header('Content-type: "text/xml"; charset="utf8"');
readfile('file.xml');
?>
```

ou

```
<?php 
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="file.xml"');
header('Content-type: "text/xml"; charset="utf8"');
echo "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<tag>Oi</tag>
</root>
";
?>
```